# Add element error by scala/spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to add some element to a set, but it does not work, what is wrong?

```
  var set = new HashSet[Int]()

  def add(a:Int){
    set.add(a)
  }

  sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3)).map(add).collect

  set.size
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the add method of set returns a unit (it has the side effect of changing the set).

When you do the map on the RDD recieved from the parallelize, you are basically changing the local version of the set at each executor, the original set on the driver is not changed.

If for example you had 3 executors, each would have a set of 1 value on that executor and then the data would go away.

In spark, you cannot rely on side effects when doing operations such as map.

A possible solution would be to do something like:

```
val s = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3)).distinct().collect.toSet
```

s would have the set.

Answer (score 1):

using `sc.parallelize`, you create a **distributed** dataset (`RDD`). Now your `add`-method (and `set` you are referencing therein) are serialized and sent to the executors. Your variable `set` only lives on the driver and does not notice the elements added to the other sets (There is no "global" `set`)

Solutions:

Use aggregate/combine methods to your RDD

```
val set = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3))
    .aggregate(Set.empty[Int])(
      (s:Set[Int],i:Int) => s + i ,
      (s1:Set[Int],s2:Set[Int]) => s1++s2
    )
```

**or** collect the data as a set

```
val set = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3)).collect().toSet
```

**or** use an accumulator:

```
import org.apache.spark.AccumulatorParam
object SetAccumulator extends AccumulatorParam[Set[Int]] {
  def zero(initialValue: Set[Int]) = Set.empty[Int]
  def addInPlace(s1: Set[Int], s2: Set[Int]) = s1 ++ s2
}

val acc = sc.accumulator(Set.empty[Int])(SetAccumulator)
sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3)).foreach(i=> acc.add(Set(i)))
val set = acc.value
```